# Power BI : How to concactenate a variable number of columns?

Tags: powerbi

I am importing data from Jira in PowerBi directly from the web. 
The data contains an unknown number of columns with similar name (for example Comment1, Comment2, Comment3, etc. depending on the maximum number of comments in the issues selected). 
I don't know how many of these columns will exist and this is variable.
Is there a way I can concatenate all columns with the same name ? (so far, I found [this](https://www.mrexcel.com/board/threads/merge-multiple-variable-columns-in-power-query.919892/) general solution)
Ideally I would like to concatenate only when there is a value.